# Why c# console app doesn't support redirection to file?

Tags: c#, console

I created a classic console app

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
```

It works except when I try to redirect output to a file

```
    myconsoleapp.exe arg1 arg2 arg3 > output.txt
```

Does C# console supports redirection ?

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: Please, show us the full code. What are you writing in stdout?

Comment: How are you trying to write ? Console.WriteLine just go to the standard output, and redirection will work.

Comment: -1 for "it doesn't work" w/o details.

Answer (score 2):

If you build the following class:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World! - {0}", args[0]);
    }
}
```

and execute

```
app.exe test > test.txt
```

you get the file test.txt with the content

```
Hello World! - test
```

If your code does different output writing please provide your methods of writing to the output.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps your messages are being sent to STDERR, not STDOUT. In that case, you need to redirect differently. From Microsoft's guidance ( http://support.microsoft.com/kb/110930 ):

> You can print the errors and standard
>   output to a single file by using the
>   "&1" command to redirect the output
>   for STDERR to STDOUT and then sending
>   the output from STDOUT to a file:
>
> `dir file.xxx 1> output.msg 2>&1`
>
> Or, you can redirect the output to one
>   place, and the errors to another.
>
> `dir file.xxx > output.msg 2> output.err`

Answer (score 0):

Without more information it is hard to figure out the problem.  One thought I had was perhaps you are using System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine to write to the debug console.  In this case you would not be able to redirect output in the same way, at least not without some more work.